# Valid text file for specific formatting

Tags: ruby, regex

I am reading the content from uploaded file and writing that content to another file. Now I want to validate the text of file which is uploaded by using regex or any other method.

My uploaded file contains following text:

```
ABC, A.B.C., A.B.C
Setoff, Set off
and, &
```

Now I want to validate the above text, So I want if more than one words are present they should separated by comma and after comma one space is required and the after last word no comma present and not any space.

Answer (score 2):

I know there's a temptation (partly because the question is tagged with it) to solve this with one big regex, but I'm partial to breaking each part of the validation into a simple rule and then checking each part separately. Not only is it easier to test and not get wrong (regexes are easy to get wrong), it means you can send back better error messages to the user. You can also add/remove rules as and when needed.

I also like using `throw` `catch` because it's not *exceptional* for something to be invalid.

```
# Using StringIO for convenience
s = StringIO.new <<MYFAKEFILE
ABC, A.B.C., A.B.C
Setoff, Set off
and, &
MYFAKEFILE

invalid_results = catch(:invalid_file){
  s.readlines.each do |line|
    throw(:invalid_file, "The words in '#{line}' are not separated by a comma followed by a space") unless line.include? ", "
    throw(:invalid_file, "The line '#{line}' ends with a comma") if line.match /,\s*$/
  end
  false # it passes validation
}

if invalid_results
  puts "File failed validation: #{result}"
  # you would handle this with an error message to the uploader      
end
```